# Merging/Combining/Appending 2 JSON files with no common values/data (in Python)

Tags: python, json, dictionary, merge

I have been trying to merge 2 JSON files that have no common data.1 files is a list of nested dictionaries while the other has **only one** dictionary(No nesting in file 2).
I tried using introduction a new key value pair ['tmp']=1 so I could merge of that key.But the code is running and exiting with a code 137 status.(sigkill).
The data of file 2 must be appended or merged within the data in file 1 ,but the lack of common parameters is not helping.I tried merging the data as python lists as well as DataFrames using pandas.

> ```
> import json import pandas as pd from pandas import DataFrame
>
> def df_crossjoin(df, df1, **kwargs):
>     df['_tmpkey'] = 1
>     df1['_tmpkey'] = 1
>
>     res = pd.merge(df, df1, on='_tmpkey', **kwargs).drop('_tmpkey', axis=1)    
>     res.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product((df.index,df1.index))    
>     df.drop('_tmpkey', axis=1, inplace=True)   
>     df1.drop('_tmpkey', axis=1, inplace=True)
>
>     return res    
>     with open("data.json",encoding='utf-8') asinput_file:
>        with open("IPAMData.json", encoding='utf-8') as input_file1:
>             data = json.load(input_file)
>             df = pd.DataFrame(data)
>
>             data1 = json.load(input_file1)
>             df1=pd.DataFrame(data1)
>             df_cartesian=df_crossjoin(df,df1,suffixes=('_left','_right'))
>             df_cartesian.to_json("FILE11.json",orient='records', lines=True)
> ```

The data in the files is: File 1-data.json:

```
 [ { "_ref": "network/ZAvMjIvMA:192.168.15.0/22/default", "comment": "ABS", "dhcp_utilization": 0, "disable": false, "enable_ddns": false, "extattrs": { "CITY": { "value": "CITY" }, "COUNTRY": { "value": "COUN" }, "Helpnow ID": { "value": "TA04" }, "OWNER": { "value": "owner@exam.com" }, "REGION": { "value": "REG" }, "SITE_CODE": { "value": "E1" }, "VLAN Type": { "value": "TYPE" }, "VLAN ID": { "value": 2 }, "VLAN DESC": { "value": "data value" }, "synchronized_with_presto": { "value": 0 } }, "members": [], "network": "192.168.15.0/22" }, { "_ref": "network/Z4gyLzA:10.4.7.0/24/default", "comment": "comment", "dhcp_utilization": 0, "disable": false, "enable_ddns": false,"extattrs": { "CITY": { "value": "ABC" }, "COUNTRY": { "value": "COUNTRY" }, "Helpnow ID": { "value": "O1" }, "OWNER": { "value": "cyz@example.com" "REGION": { "value": "REGION" }, "SITE_CODE": { "value": "T1" }, "VLAN Type": { "value": "TN" }, "VLAN ID": { "value": 1612 }, "VLAN DESC": { "value": "DESC" }, "synchronized_with_presto": { "value": 0 } }, "members": [], "network": "10.4.7.0/22" },....]
```

file 2 IPAMData.json:

```
[ { "_ref": "ipam:statistics/ZAujjMjIvMA:default/192.168.15.0/22", "network": "192.168.15.0", "utilization": 640 }, { "_ref": "ipam:statistics/ZG5AuIyLzA:default/10.4.7.0/22", "network": "10.4.7.0", "utilization": 9 }, ... ]
```

Output:Process finished with exit code 137 (interrupted by signal 9: SIGKILL)

Expected Output can be something like this:

```
 [ { "_ref": "network/ZAvMjIvMA:192.168.15.0/22/default", "comment": "ABS","_ref": "ipam:statistics/ZAMjIvMA:default/192.168.15.0/22", "network": "192.168.15.0", "utilization": 640, "dhcp_utilization": 0, "disable": false, "enable_ddns": false,  "extattrs": { "CITY": { "value": "CITY" }, "COUNTRY": { "value": "COUN" }, "Helpnow ID": { "value": "TA04" }, "OWNER": { "value": "owner@exam.com" }, "REGION": { "value": "REG" }, "SITE_CODE": { "value": "E1" }, "VLAN Type": { "value": "TYPE" }, "VLAN ID": { "value": 2 }, "VLAN DESC": { "value": "data value" }, "synchronized_with_presto": { "value": 0 } }, "members": [], "network": "192.168.15.0/22" } { "_ref": "network/Z4gyLzA:10.4.7.0/24/default", "comment": "comment","_ref": "ipam:statistics/ZG5AuIyLzA:default/10.4.7.0/22", "network": "10.4.7.0", "utilization": 9 , "dhcp_utilization": 0, "disable": false, "enable_ddns": false, "extattrs": { "CITY": { "value": "ABC" }, "COUNTRY": { "value": "COUNTRY" }, "Helpnow ID": { "value": "O1" }, "OWNER": { "value": "cyz@example.com" "REGION": { "value": "REGION" }, "SITE_CODE": { "value": "T1" }, "VLAN Type": { "value": "TN" }, "VLAN ID": { "value": 1612 }, "VLAN DESC": { "value": "DESC" }, "synchronized_with_presto": { "value": 0 } }, "members": [], "network": "10.4.7.0/22" },....]
```

The data in file 2 has to be appended to the data in file 1 where in each dictionary in file 2 corresponds to the dictionaries in file 1 in the same order.

Comment: Could you please format correctly the code?

Comment: Is this readable?

Comment: You should try to give an example of input and the expected output. BTW as currently shown second json is also a list even it is contains one single dict.

Comment: The input sample data is what I have shown as .json files.The problem in the current code is that,It is merging the same data twice on the key.I can't understand why.

Comment: Your example output cannot be a valid Json because it contains twice the same key `"_ref"` with different values. You could produce it with raw string processing but not with Json processing.

Comment: Is it possible to somehow only append the 'utilization' key to the data in file 1?